# A switch to toggle only when going from 0 to 1

Tags: logic, circuit

Maybe stupid question but, is there any possible way using logic gates to make a circuit that will get one input (0/1) and will give one output (0/1) and the output will only toggle when the input change from 0 to 1 and stay the same when the input change from 1 to 0?

Comment: What about the `Xor` operation? Xoring `1` with an input, inverts it while xoring with `0` doesn't change the input.

Comment: but the xor has 2 inputs , i want to give one input and when the input goes from 0 to 1 i want the output to change (it doesn't matter if its 0 or 1 i just want the toggle) and when the input goes from 1 to 0 i want the output to remain the same

Comment: Can you use the previous output of the algorithm as another input? If you can it might solve the problem.